# PHP: Getting data from a JSON file

Tags: php, json

I have a json input which simplified version is:

```
{
"result": {
    "status": 1,
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "TF_WEAPON_EXAMPLE",
            "defindex": 0,
            "craft_material_type": "weapon",
            "used_by_classes": [
                "Scout",
                "Pyro"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "TF_WEAPON_BOTTLE",
            "defindex": 1,
            "craft_material_type": "weapon",
            "used_by_classes": [
                "Demoman"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Paint Can 5",
            "defindex": 5031,
            "craft_material_type": "tool",
            "used_by_classes": [

            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I want to get the values of each "used_by_classes" and so I tried to use:

```
$schema_items = $json['result']['items'];
foreach($schema_item['used_by_classes'] as $class)
{
   echo $class;
}
```

Which lead me to `Invalid query: Unknown column 'class' in 'field list'`

How should I proceed ? Share some code if you can.

Thanks!

Comment: In foreach you have `$schema_item` instead of `$schema_items`.

Comment: You have «s» missing in the `foreach` variable. Try `foreach($schema_items['used_by_classes'] as $class)`

Comment: The error message you quoted sounds more like a database/SQL error …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by replacing with `$key => $class`, like this:

```
foreach($schema_item['used_by_classes'] as $key => $class)
{
   echo $class;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a misspelling in your code that is generating the error

```
$schema_items = $json['result']['items'];
foreach($schema_item['used_by_classes'] as $class)
      //^ here it should be $schema_items
{
   echo $class;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do here

```
foreach($item in $schema_items){
    echo $item["used_by_classes"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1st of all you have Object not Array in JSON. So you should do:

```
$schema_items = $json->result->items;
foreach($schema_items as $class)
{
    print_r($class->used_by_classes); // your array with "used_by_classes" values
}
```

Comment: FALSE op didn't state if he decoded as an associative array or object though

Comment: There's no code for decoding JSON, so I assumed `json_decode` with default params.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would parse it:

**PHP:**

```
$json = json_decode($data, true);
$result = $json['result'];
$schema_items = $result['items'];

foreach($schema_items as $class)
{
    foreach($class['used_by_classes'] as $SubClass)
    {
        echo $SubClass."<br />";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Scout
Pyro
Demoman
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://eval.in/104907)</kbd>